# Como formatar strings e armazena-las em um vetor dinâmico

Tags: c, array, string, memória, alocação

Em diversas partes do meu código acabo precisando usar comandos do bash para executar programas no Ubuntu. Para isso, formato o comando usando sprintf e depois executo com a função system.

Ex:

```
sprintf(sprintfoutput, "makeblastdb -in %s -dbtype prot -out SASBT_BLASTDB > /dev/null", one_rawreference);
system((char *)sprintfoutput);
```

Porém, notem que o tamanho de sprintfoutput varia de acordo com a "one_rawreference", cujo valor é definido pelo usuário. Como posso fazer para que o tamanho do sprintfoutput seja igual ao tamanho da minha string formatada?

Observação: Faço esse tipo de coisa mais de 40 vezes no meu código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente a função asprintf(), que aloca e retorna o buffer necessário para acomodar o resultado. Além de retornar o tamanho certo, é muito mais seguro.

Por ser uma extensão da GNU libc, você precisa definir a macro

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
```

antes de

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

Comment: Lembrando que `asprintf()` se trata de uma *extensão GNU* e não faz parte do padrão `C` (e nem do `POSIX`).

Answer (score 1):

A função `snprintf()` da biblioteca padrão `stdio.h` é capaz de calcular o tamanho necessário para se acomodar a string formatada. O segredo é passar um *buffer* `NULL`, com tamanho `0`, fazendo com que `snprintf()` retorne a quantidade de bytes necessários para acomodar a string formatada, veja só:

```
size_t tam = snprintf( NULL, 0, "makeblastdb -in %s -dbtype prot -out SASBT_BLASTDB > /dev/null", one_rawreference );
```

Segue um exemplo (testado) baseado na sua necessidade:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * formatar_comando( char const * one_rawreference )
{
    /* String de formatacao */
    const char * fmt = "makeblastdb -in %s -dbtype prot -out SASBT_BLASTDB > /dev/null";

    /* Calcula tamanho necessario para acomodar a string formatada */
    size_t tam = snprintf( NULL, 0, fmt, one_rawreference );

    /* Aloca a memoria necessaria para acomodar a string formatada */
    char * output = malloc( tam + 1 );

    /* Formata string efetivamente */
    sprintf( output, fmt, one_rawreference );

    /* Retorna */
    return output;
}


int main( void )
{
    /* Formatacao do comando em vetor dinamico */
    char * cmd = formatar_comando( "foobar" );

    /* Exibe o comando que sera executado */
    printf("Comando: %s\n", cmd );

    /* Execucao do comando */
    system(cmd);

    /* Libera memoria do vetor dinamico usada para formatacao */
    free(cmd);

    /* Sucesso */
    return 0;
}
```

A execução do seu comando pode ser encapsulada completamente dentro de uma unica função, que seria capaz de alocar somente a memoria necessária para a formatação da string, veja só:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int executar_makeblastdb( char const * one_rawreference )
{
    /* String de formatacao */
    const char * fmt = "makeblastdb -in %s -dbtype prot -out SASBT_BLASTDB > /dev/null";

    /* Calcula tamanho necessario para acomodar a string formatada */
    size_t tam = snprintf( NULL, 0, fmt, one_rawreference );

    /* Aloca a memoria necessaria para acomodar a string formatada */
    char * cmd = malloc( tam + 1 );

    /* Formata string */
    sprintf( cmd, fmt, one_rawreference );

    /* Executa comando */
    int ret = system(cmd);

    /* Libera a memoria ocupada */
    free(cmd);

    /* Retorna status da execucao do comando */
    return ret;
}


int main( void )
{
    int ret = executar_makeblastdb( "foobar" );

    if( ret < 0 )
    {
        printf("Erro executando comando.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Comando executado com sucesso.\n");
    return 0;
}
```